# How to make a for-loop wait some time before going through the loop again

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display an array of slides and each slide has a value which tells the programm how long it should be displayed for. Since the slides are stored in an array I thought about just looping through the array, display the current slide and then just wait the amount of time at the end before looping again.

So this is my attempt:

```
for (let  i= 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.currentSlide = this.slides[i]
  }, this.slides[i].slidetime * 1000);
}
```

I even tried doing it like this:

```
for (let  i= 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
  this.currentSlide = this.slides[i];
  this.wait(this.slides[i].slidetime);
}

wait(seconds) {
  setTimeout(() => {}, seconds * 1000);
}
```

But it didn't make a difference.

Comment: setTimeout is *asynchronous*, it won't block the for loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay i see... so what would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the tag `angular` so you can use `Observables` for this:

```
from(this.slides).pipe(
  concatMap((slide) => of(slide).pipe(
    tap((slide) => this.currentSlide = slide),
    delay(slide.slideTime)
  ))
).subscribe()
```

If observables are a bit too tricky for you, you can use the `await/async` method:

```
async goThroughSlides(): Promise<void> {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
    this.currentSlide = this.slides[i];
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, this.currentSlide.slideTime));
  }
}
```

I made an example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifwyym)

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me ^^

Answer (score -1):

create another variable that will hold the values for slides and use it in your html.

```
newSlides: any;

for(let i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++){
        let slide = this.slides[i];
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.newSlides.push(slide);
        }, 2000*(i+1));
    }
```